# 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a class "Settings" written in VB.NET. I am trying to use this class in a console application written in C#. When I instantiate Settings class in my console application I am getting this exception:

'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I have tried changing launch and activation permissions in DCOM Config.

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SqlConnection CN = null;
                Settings S = new Settings();// Exception throws here
                CN = new SqlConnection(S.GetLocalSetting("CnStr"));
            }
        }
```

Settings class imports these namespaces:

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.EnterpriseServices
 Imports System.Xml
 Imports Data.Encryption

// Constructor
Public Sub New()

    End Sub
```

And has many methods which are used to get and delete settings, to connect to database etc.

Comment: It seems like a permissions issue... Can you show the `Settings` class?

Comment: I also think it must be a file permission issue. Please make sure that you have access to the file you want to use.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have edited the question to give you some insight about settings class.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I added the constructor. Class does not do anything inside the constructor.

Comment: It's definitely a permission issue (one of the imports/namespaces) as I mentioned before, try running VS as an Administrator.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ. But i  am already running as an admin.

Comment: So you are running VS as an Admin already or are you logged in as an Admin or both? In any case, comment out the `Imports System.EnterpriseServices` and any other code referencing that namespace and try it again; continue this until you find what code is causing the issue. This all comes down to debugging to at least find out what code is causing the issue.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i am running VS as an Admin. Not logged in as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The classes in Data.Encryption requires administrator permissions to run, and that's why you got this exception.

You try run your visual studio in administrator mode?

Comment: I am running as an admin.